# WordPress API Access sub-pages

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I have created a blog on Wordpress.com, I can access the api and returned posts from the homepage with this:

https://public-api.wordpress.com/rest/v1/sites/{siteID}/

So my blog is access via URL at something like www.blog.home.blog

However I have a second page that is at www.blog.home.blog/secondPage

The API doesn't return Posts from this URL. Trying to understand what I need to change to the API URL to return posts from this second page?

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the ID of this page/post you are trying to access. It will be something like `https://public-api.wordpress.com/rest/v1.1/sites/$site/posts/$post_ID` And to get all the posts you can use `https://public-api.wordpress.com/rest/v1.1/sites/$site/posts/`

More info is available [here](https://developer.wordpress.com/docs/api/1.1/get/sites/%24site/posts/%24post_ID/) at the official wordpress.com documentation for developers.

Comment: But surely they should come back when I do the call for all the posts? using https://developer.wordpress.com/docs/api/1.1/get/sites/$site/posts

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I had used the wrong url. Instead the one for the API a had posted the one to the documentation. It is now corrected.

Comment: Thanks, I still think that the sub page posts should come back when I do https://public-api.wordpress.com/rest/v1.1/sites/$site/posts, As I thought that would return the whole index of the site

Comment: that should return all the posts. Check the documentation for it [here](https://developer.wordpress.com/docs/api/1.1/get/sites/%24site/posts/)